# How to use Linq Query in Object Data Source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, objectdatasource

If I have the following query code :

```
DataTable loans =Loans_HR.CalcLoans(2011, 7, 2013);
var groupedData = from b in loans.AsEnumerable()    
                  group b by b.Field<int>("loan_code") & b.Field<int>("emp_num") into f
                  select f.CopyToDataTable();
```

Now I want to use the `groupedData` As a result in my `ObjectDataSource` How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
group b by new {b.Field<int>("loan_code"), b.Field<int>("emp_num")}
```

P.S. Perhaps, you must use some aggregates.

Comment: hmmm, I just want to use `groupedData` as a data source in my objectdatasource ?

Comment: What do you meant by grouped data? Can you provide some source data and desired grouped data?

Comment: I mean my new datatable `var groupedData`

Comment: I don't know what is your old DataTable and what will be the new one.